# avoid executing a DB query in loop

Tags: java, sql

I have a table as below,

```
process_name |  startTime             | endTime               | parent_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
chrome       |  2019-03-06 00:48:27   | 2019-03-06 00:48:58   | 111
chrome       |  2019-03-07 00:48:27   | 2019-03-07 00:48:58   | 112
firefox      |  2019-03-08 00:48:27   | 2019-03-08 00:48:58   | 113
IE           |  2019-03-09 00:48:27   | 2019-03-09 00:48:58   | 114
firefox      |  2019-03-10 00:48:27   | 2019-03-10 00:48:58   | 115
chrome       |  2019-03-11 00:48:27   | 2019-03-11 00:48:58   | 116
```

Some points from the table,

1. Same `process_name` can be found under different `parent_ids`.
2. I already know the `process_name` and have an `ArrayList` of `parent_ids` where it exists.

For a given `process_name`, I need to find `startTime` and `endTime` for all of the `parent_ids` present in my `ArrayList`.

All I can think of is using a `for` loop and execute the below query.

```
select startTime, endTime from myTable where parent_id = ? and process_name=?
```

Can I avoid executing this query in a loop and follow some other better approach?

I use `Derby` at this moment but the DB may get changed to `Oracle`.

Comment: Is parent_id stored in a table? If so you can perform a JOIN.

Comment: why you need loop? you can just filter by process_name

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple approaches to solve this problem :

1. As Svend Suggested, Since you already have `process_name`, You can get all the start and end times for that process name.
2. Another approach is to prepare a string of `parent_id`s first, and then query it to the database using a single query:

Code:

```
String s = "(";
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    if(i<list.length-1) s+=list[i] + ",";
    else s+= ""+ list[i] + ")";
}

String query = " select startTime, endTime from myTable where parent_id IN " + s + " and process_name=?";
```

Comment: op wants to avoid loop

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, OP doesn't meant to say that he doesn't want to do a loop at all, he just doesn't want to do a loop of SQL queries

Comment: I guess this would be better using Christian's `?` formatting, as it would be less injection attack prone... though that shouldn't matter too much in this specific case, as we're probably in control of what's in `list`...

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to execute a query in a loop. Instead, why don't you fetch all the records belonging to a given process at once. Maybe using GROUPBY clause for the process_name along with aggregate functions on other columns [if you need to perform anything upon those other columns and avoid doing via code by yourself]
Once you have all the records in hand, then the startTime and endTime can be used for your further processing.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to just do:

```
select parent_id, startTime, endTime from myTable where process_name=?
```

And get the values for all `parent_id` values, and then filter those on your `ArrayList` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation of the solution of @prakhar-londhe you might also use parameters in the `in` clause as in

```
String query = " select startTime, endTime from myTable where parent_id IN (?, ?, ?) and process_name = ?";
```

and then add a parameter for each `parent_id`. Of course you'd still have to assemble the `query` (to put a `?` inside the parentheses for each `parent_id`) as well as the parameter list in a loop.